# Why is 'ls' being created by execve() call and not fork()

Tags: linux, exec, fork

From my understanding whenever you type a command such as 'ls' in your shell, the parent process which is my shell duplicates itself using fork() system call and then uses the exec() system call to replace it with the new process, in this case 'ls' once the it exits, the control is handed back to my shell.

However when I was run strace on 'ls' I only see execve() call and no fork and the control is still handed back to my shell. Kind of confused here...

```
$ strace ls
execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], 0x7ffd938934e0 /* 25 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1134000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6ea9e38000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23255, ...}) = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. When you run `strace ls` there are even two forks. The shell forks itself and uses `exec()` to run `strace` and strace does the same to run `ls`.

You don't see the fork in the strace output because strace prints all system calls that originate from **strace's child process** and at that point in time the fork already happened:

1. `bash` forks and runs `strace`
2. `strace` forks
3. The parent `strace` attaches to the child process to intercept all system calls.

   *You only see system calls from this point on.*
4. The child `strace` runs `ls` using `execve()`

One way to see the forks happen, is to attach `strace` "from the outside":

- Use `echo $$` to get the process id of the shell
- Run `strace -f --attach=PID` with "PID" replaced by the process id from above **in another console**.
- Run `ls` in the first shell
- In the other console window you'll see all system calls happening in the shell and the forked children (including the `fork()`/`clone()` calls).
- Use CTRL+C in the second console to stop strace.

One other thing to mention is that `fork()` on current Linux kernels is implemented using the `clone()` system call, so you'll probably see `clone(…)` instead of `fork()` in the strace output.

Comment: Thank you! Should've thought of that before!!

Comment: or run a shell explicitly under `strace`, something like `strace -etrace=clone,execve,write,exit_group -f sh -c 'ls foo; echo hi'`